# PS & JSON : Removing empty lists / values recursively

Tags: json, powershell, recursion

I built a PSObject, once converted to JSON, looking like this

```
{
"add": {
    "windows": {
        "files": [],
        "directories": []
    },
    "Applications": [
        {
            "processfile": {
                "sha2": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "name": "Aurelien test.exe"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Certificates": [],
    "webdomains": [],
    "ips_hosts": [],
    "Extensions": {
        "names": [],
        "scheduled": false,
        "features": []
    },
    "linux": {
        "files": [],
        "directories": []
    },
    "mac": {
        "files": [],
        "directories": []
    }
},
"remove": {
    "Applications": [],
    "Certificates": [],
    "webdomains": [],
    "ips_hosts": [],
    "Extensions": {
        "names": [],
        "scheduled": false,
        "features": []
    },
    "windows": {
        "files": [],
        "directories": []
    },
    "linux": {
        "files": [],
        "directories": []
    },
    "mac": {
        "files": [],
        "directories": []
    }
}
}
```

I need to remove the empty lists as it will be used as a HTTP body to update some data via API. In this example, file name & file hash will be added to a security policy

```
{
    "add": {
        "Applications": [
            {
                "processfile": {
                    "sha2": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                    "name": "Aurelien test.exe"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

For that, I've tried (and failed) attempts of recursive ways, and ended up manually parsing each property with the following function which :

- Parses properties of my original PSObject
- Look for Nested content ("add" and "remove" hives) and make a rescursive call for that
- Lookup for every properties manually, and exclude them via the following code `$obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property`

  ```
   function Optimize-SepCloudAllowListPolicyObject {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
       [PSObject]
       $obj
   )

   process {
       # Listing all properties of the object
       $AllProperties = $obj | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
       foreach ($property in $AllProperties) {
           switch ($property) {
               { $_ -in @("add", "remove") } {
                   # recursively call the function to dig deeper
                   Optimize-SepCloudAllowListPolicyObject $obj.$property
               }
               "applications" {
                   if ($obj.$property.processfile.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove Applications property
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "webdomains" {
                   if ($obj.$property.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove webdomains property
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "certificates" {
                   if ($obj.$property.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove certificates property
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "ips_hosts" {
                   if ($obj.$property.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove ips_hosts property
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "extensions" {
                   if ($obj.$property.names.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove extensions property
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "linux" {
                   # Checking linux files
                   if ($obj.$property.linux.files.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove linux files property only
                       $obj.$property = $obj.$property | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "files"
                   }
                   # Checking linux folders
                   if ($obj.$property.linux.directories.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove linux folders property only
                       $obj.$property = $obj.$property | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "directories"
                   }
               }
               "windows" {
                   # Checking windows files
                   if ($obj.$property.windows.files.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove windows files property only
                       $obj.$property = $obj.$property | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "files"
                   }
                   # Checking windows folders
                   if ($obj.$property.windows.directories.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove windows folders property only
                       $obj.$property = $obj.$property | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "directories"
                   }
               }
               "mac" {
                   # Checking mac files
                   if ($obj.$property.mac.files.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove mac files property only
                       $obj.$property = $obj.$property | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "files"
                   }
                   # Checking mac folders
                   if ($obj.$property.mac.directories.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove mac folders property only
                       $obj.$property = $obj.$property | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "directories"
                   }
               }
               Default {}
           }
       }

       return $obj
   }
  ```

  }

I have a couple of issues:

- First, only the last item of my obj (`$obj[-1]`) list looks remotely similar to my end goal, so I assume I'm not looping correctly somehow
- Then, not all properties are removed. From what I could debug myself, it looks like my way of removing a property is correct, but not correctly returned when recursively calling the function under the 1st nested object ("add" and "remove" in this case)

Could I get any pointers on how to update this function to get closer to my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the expected result with the following function.
Some changes :

- reworked the "add" and "remove" switches
- tested if they were empty, if so, remove them
- recursively call only once

  ```
   function Optimize-SepCloudAllowListPolicyObject {

   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
       [PSObject]
       $obj
   )

   process {
       # Listing all properties of the object
       $AllProperties = $obj | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
       foreach ($property in $AllProperties) {
           switch ($property) {
               "add" {
                   # recursively call the function to dig deeper
                   $obj.add = Optimize-SepCloudAllowListPolicyObject $obj.$property
                   # Verify if the add object has no properties
                   if (($obj.add | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove the "add"  property from the object
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "remove" {
                   # recursively call the function to dig deeper
                   $obj.remove = Optimize-SepCloudAllowListPolicyObject $obj.$property
                   # Verify if the remove object has no properties
                   if (($obj.remove | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove the "remove" property from the object
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "applications" {
                   if ($obj.$property.processfile.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove Applications property
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "webdomains" {
                   if ($obj.$property.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove webdomains property
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "certificates" {
                   if ($obj.$property.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove certificates property
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "ips_hosts" {
                   if ($obj.$property.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove ips_hosts property
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "extensions" {
                   if ($obj.$property.names.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove extensions property
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "linux" {
                   # Checking linux files
                   if ($obj.$property.files.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove linux files property only
                       $obj.$property = $obj.$property | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "files"
                   }
                   # Checking linux folders
                   if ($obj.$property.directories.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove linux folders property only
                       $obj.$property = $obj.$property | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "directories"
                   }
                   # If both files and folders are empty, remove the property
                   if ($obj.$property.files.count -eq 0 -and $obj.$property.directories.count -eq 0) {
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "windows" {
                   # Checking windows files
                   if ($obj.$property.files.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove windows files property only
                       $obj.$property = $obj.$property | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "files"
                   }
                   # Checking windows folders
                   if ($obj.$property.directories.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove windows folders property only
                       $obj.$property = $obj.$property | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "directories"
                   }
                   # If both files and folders are empty, remove the property
                   if ($obj.$property.files.count -eq 0 -and $obj.$property.directories.count -eq 0) {
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               "mac" {
                   # Checking mac files
                   if ($obj.$property.files.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove mac files property only
                       $obj.$property = $obj.$property | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "files"
                   }
                   # Checking mac folders
                   if ($obj.$property.directories.count -eq 0) {
                       # Remove mac folders property only
                       $obj.$property = $obj.$property | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "directories"
                   }
                   # If both files and folders are empty, remove the property
                   if ($obj.$property.files.count -eq 0 -and $obj.$property.directories.count -eq 0) {
                       $obj = $obj | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $property
                   }
               }
               Default {}
           }
       }
       return $obj
   }
  ```

  }